# Is there any way to get around a Security Sandbox violation when a swf is loading another swf which loads another swf?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a AS3 swf [1] that is loading another AS2 swf [2] which is loading another AS3 swf [3].

I'm getting a Security Sandbox violation on the AS2 swf trying to access the last AS3 swf (3), but I'm using Security.allowDomain("*") in practically all the classes of the first AS3 swf (1). Is there any way to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's not just a security sandbox issue, you simply CANNOT load an as3 file into an as2 file

"SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0 cannot load SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0. "